# Is it possible to have required merge checks on Bitbucket Server

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have managed to set up some [custom checks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/suggest-or-require-checks-before-a-merge-856691474.html) on Bitbucket server and they work ok.

However I seemingly need [Bitbucket Premium](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-cloud-premium-plan-856833380.html) to make them required, but I don't think there is a Premium option for Bitbucket Server. So how do I setup required merge checks for Bitbucket Server?

Answer (score 0):

You've linked to a Bitbucket Cloud document, but you're asking about Bitbucket Server.

You need to have your custom merge checks return `RepositoryHookResult.rejected(String summaryMessage, String detailedMessage)` (or the equivalent in your language of choice) to Bitbucket Server upon failure. https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/tutorials-and-examples/controlling-when-pull-requests-can-be-merged/ has some example code.